# Writing a SQL query using postgis geometry on the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm fairly new to writing SQL queries, so thanks in advance. I have a postgres table called geo_areas. This table contains a list of cities, towns and states. I have a column called type which specifies whether it is a city or town or state. I also have a column called Geometry which holds the geometry of the said name. It looks similar to this,

```
Name, Type, Geometry

Philadelphia, Town, XXXXXXXXXX
Pennsylvania, State, XXXXXXXXXXX
Pittsburgh, Town, XXXXXXXXXXX
Porsche, City, XXXXXXXXX
```

I need to write a query that lists all the other names that is contained in it's geometry, similar to this.

```
Name, Type, Contains

Pennsylvania, State, [Porsche, Pittsburg, Philadelphia]
Porsche, City, [Philadelphia, Pittsburgh]
Philadelphia, Town, []
Pittsburgh, Town, []
```

Any help for a step in the right direction is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you want the geometry contained  in a state   you could  try

```
select t2.* 
from  my_table t1  
inner join my_table t2 on st_dwithin(t1.geom,t2.geom, 0) 
and t1.type='State' 
and t2.type!='State'
```

or for st_contains

```
select t2.* 
from  my_table t1  
inner join my_table t2 on st_contains(t2.geom,t1.geom) 
and t1.type='State' 
and t2.type!='State'
```

Comment: The result of that gives me `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "t2"`

Comment: answer updated .. wrong  my_table2 instead of my_table t2

Comment: appreciate it! However I think I need to be using contains, but it doesn't look like it works.                                                                                                                `select t2.* 
  from  my_table t1  
  inner join my_table t2 on st_contains(ST_GeomFromText(t1.geom=, 4326)) 
  and t1.type='state' 
  and t2.type!='state';`